# Update query to fix incorrect references between two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, firebird

I have a table `task` containing e.g.

```
task_id  group_id  plantype
1        0          1 
13       1          0
14       1          0
15       1          0
```

This indicates tasks 13,14,15 grouped under task 1.
Field `plantype` also indicates if we are dealing with a group or not.

I have a second table `allocations` containing allocations for the tasks (N-1), i.e. it also contains field `task_id`

There are records in `allocations` that incorrectly point to group records (remains of an earlier conversion that had errors):

```
alloc_id       task_id
xxx            1
```

They should point to the 'first' task within that group, 'first' being the lowest `task_id`

```
alloc_id       task_id
xxx            13
```

How do I construct my update query?

The offending allocations are easy to find because groups can't have allocations:

```
select a.alloc_id,t.task_id from alloc a, task t 
where a.task_id=t.task_id 
and coalesce(t.plantype,0) = 1
```

I would need the `task_id`s from there as the `group_id` to determine the `min(task_id)` for,
and I would need the `allocid`s to select the allocation records to update

Determining the minimum `task_id` for a group:

```
select group_id,min(task_id) as task_min_id
from task 
group by group_id
```

Assembling it all together it starts to look like:

```
update alloc 
set task_id = 
    (
    select min(task_id) as task_min_id
    from task 
    where group_id = 
      (
      select t.task_id from alloc a, task t 
      where a.task_id=t.task_id 
      and coalesce(t.plantype,0) = 1
      )        
    group by group_id
    )

where alloc_id in 
  (
  select a.alloc_id from alloc a, task t 
  where a.task_id=t.task_id 
  and coalesce(t.plantype,0) = 1
  )
```

but I'm stranding here. This in itself gives a "*multiple rows in singleton select*" error. I have tried putting other/more tables aliases in, but I doubt that the two subselects on `alloc a, task t` will be in sync anyway.

**What should my query be?**

I'm trying in Firebird right now, but I have to get this working in SQL Server and Oracle as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts to this.  One is getting the right records to update.  I think you can do this with `in` with a subquery (or using `exists)`.  The other is the `update`.  I believe the following will work in SQL Server and Oracle and probably Firebird:

```
update allocations a
    set task_id = (select min(t.task_id)
                   from task t
                   where t.group_id = a.task_id and
                         t.planttype = 0
                  )
    where a.task_id in (select t.task_id from task t where t.planttype = 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think this would work:

```
update allocations a1
   set task_id =
     (
 select min (task_id)
   from task
  where group_id = a1.task_id);
```